# Can I use the software on my mac to help me claim my eligibility for the Up-to-date-program, so I get Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos

I recently got a new MAcbook pro, and while I was exploring features on the Apple site and learning to make the transition to a Mac from a PC, I noticed there was an up-to-date program. I do not have any receipts or the papers from the shipping to prove when I bought my mac and they denied my first attempt. I would like to get the new software, but i need to know if there is any certificate installed to help me prove I bought my mac.

Comment: As for anything installed on your Mac itself: a clean reinstall would very likely also update all that, so that would imply you could easily make a 2006 MacBook look like it were purchased yesterday. I assume Apple has records about when you first connected it to the Internet, but apparently they don't want to use those. (As an aside: I guess making some effort to get the right paperwork will also be very helpful when you need to use the warranty? Repairs might cost you much more than the ML update!)

Answer (score 1):

If you bought your Mac on-line directly from Apple, then your name, date of purchase and serial number of your Mac are enough.

It worked fine to upgrade my new MacBook Air (bought on apple.fr) to Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0):

Without receipts there is no way to get your mountain lion upgrade for free:

> To receive your OS X Mountain Lion upgrade, you must complete the order form and provide an electronic copy of a dated, itemized sales receipt indicating the marketing part number(s) of the qualifying product(s) purchased. Order acknowledgments, packing slips, and purchase order copies are not valid.

Quoted from the apple website: [osx up to date](http://www.apple.com/osx/uptodate/)

Answer (score 0):

If you bought it online, Apple should have emailed you a receipt after your purchase. If you got it direct from an Apple Store, I think all you need is the serial number of your machine, which can be found under `` > `About This Mac`>`More Info`

 Hope this helps!